# Converting jQuery Modal Service to AngularJS directive doesn't allow 2 way binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've inherited another legacy system that a previous colleague was working on, he was asked to remove server side components from an app and replace them with AngularJS... it's an old JSP system and everything is a bit of a hack. Anyway, there is a jQuery library within the old system that produces Modal Windows, rather than have to add UI-Bootstrap my colleague converted this jQuery service to an AngularJS directive and it kind of works... but with one exception, here is the directive code...

```
   .directive('popupWindow', ['$document', '$compile', function ($document, $compile, MessagesService) {

        "use strict";

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var newPopup = new Basebox({

                        contentUrl: '/ng/xtemplate/widgets/CCC/' + scope.getType + '.html',
                        type: 'regular',
                        id: 'sf-basebox',
                        hideBackground: false,
                        overlay: true,
                        resolveTest: {getType: scope.getType, message: scope.message, config: scope.config }, // this is appended to the Modal Window as a ng-init and it renders correctly!
                        closeOnOverlay: false,
                        closeIcon: true,
                        checkOldIe: true,
                        afterContentLoad: function () {
                            $compile($document.find("#basebox"))(scope);
                            scope.$apply();
                        }
                    });

                    newPopup.create();

                    }
                });

            }
        };
    }]);
```

Now this works as it allows us to import HTML templates, it produces the Modal Window and allows us to set various properties, it also allows is to pass data objects (see the `resolveTest` property) to the controller of the model window. Everything works! Anything within the angularJS templating `{{ }}` is rendered and we can use angular directives such as `ng-init, ng-repeat`, etc, etc... however when trying to have two way binding between the view and the controller nothing seems to work, the data gets rendered from the controller to the view but not the other way around. The view never updates... here is the view and the controller

```
.controller('reportModelCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.val = {};
    $scope.val.foo = 'blue';   
})
```

Here is the view...

```
<div ng-controller="reportModelCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="val.foo"> {{ val.foo }} this is by default 'blue' but never updates
</div>
```

Like I say, I dynamically add an `ng-init` to the modal template and this works, but when I amend the text box nothing happens. Can anyone think of something I'm missing? Even if I try to update values using methods in the controller and `ng-click` in the view nothing is updated. Calling `$scope.$apply()` just results in an error. Do I need to add a form to my view? Sorry the jQuery Basebox library isn't included here but I just thought it would add to the confusion. I just really want suggestions or hints to getting the two way binding to work rather than a full answer.

Comment: I don't see how this will work - the BaseBox library will not be Angular aware, so passing values to it and then compiling the DOM will be fine, but how would anything you do in the Basebox functionality know to update bindings and watch for changes etc?

Comment: I think that's what I'm trying to find out... I can't think of a way to get the two way binding to work...

Comment: I think the way would be to ditch the BaseBox code and rewrite it's functionality into your directive in the Angular way. But that would be a lot of work :(

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, $compiling as is done with the scope will make variables available to the scope. However I believe you're creating an isolated scope in your popup directive. I typically pass my own scope into a modal directive and then compile the HTML on that, so that's one possibility. There's a number of ways to skin this cat. I'd recommend reading the AngularUI modal directive and the AngularFoundations one too.

Comment: To be more specific `scope: {}` will make your directive have an empty isolated scope. I'd remove it unless you have a reason for it.